# Use PHP Associative Array in If Condition

Tags: php, arrays, file, directory, conditional-statements

I have a question about the meaning of the statement in the if the condition, and the purpose of it. I've posted the complete PHP code below. This is a code from another person that I am working on currently, and my question is about a specific line of code (plz see the next paragraph for my question).

```
<?php
    $dir = '../assets/videos/';             
    if(is_dir($dir)) {
        $filesread = array();
        $dh = opendir($dir);
        print_r($filesread);
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                //returns all file names wihout extension
                $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file);    
                if($filesread[$withoutExt] !== true) {                                      
                    $hasSQL = false;                                        
                    foreach($films as $f) {                                         
                        if($f['file_name'] == $withoutExt) {                                            
                            echo '
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                                        <a href="'.$dir.$f['file_name'].'.mp4" target="_blank">'.$withoutExt.'</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        [<a class="edit" id="'.$f['filmID'].'" data-title="'.$f['title'].'" data-category="'.$f['categoryID'].'" data-file-name="'.$f['file_name'].'" data-desc="'.$f['description'].'">Edit</a>]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[<a href="films.php?remove='.$f['filmID'].'">Remove</a>]
                                    </div>
                                </div><br />';
                            $hasSQL = true;
                            print_r($withoutExt);
                        }
                    }
                    if($hasSQL == false) { 
                        echo '
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                    <a href="'.$dir.$withoutExt.'.jpg" target="_blank">'.$withoutExt.'</a>: <strong>DOES NOT HAVE DATA</strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                    [<a class="add" data-file-name="'.$withoutExt.'"">Add Data</a>]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[<a href="films.php?remove='.urlencode($withoutExt).'">Remove</a>]
                                </div>
                            </div><br />';
                    }
                    $filesread[$withoutExt] = true;
                }   
            }
        }                       
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid directory';                                   
    }
?>
```

In this php code, I am not really sure what does the statement `if($filesread[$withoutExt] !== true)` mean.

```
  if($filesread[$withoutExt] !== true) {//code to be excute}
```

I do not know what is `$filesread[$withoutExt]`. What I know is `$filesread = array();` and `$withoutExt` is filename without extension. My guess is that the programmer was trying to use `$withoutEx`t as a key to get the value from `$filesread` array, but $`filesread` is an empty array. How could he get the value from an empty array? Does anyone understand the meaning of `$filesread[$withoutExt]`, and the purpose of this if statement? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$filesread` is an array containing file names without an extension as keys. With flags of true for items one assumes have been listed already.  The assignment happens after the output:

```
$filesread[$withoutExt] = true;
```

My guess would be that there may be multiple filenames containing different extensions.  Perhaps subtitles or thumbnail files for each film.  And you wouldn't want to list them more than once.

Hence a check:

```
$filesread[$withoutExt] !== true
```

Which reads does the array not hold a value of true for the without extension key.

However the expression could just as easily be written here as:

```
!isset($filesread[$withoutExt])
```

But as this is an extract of code, the array may contain other values assigned elsewhere.

On first run the array key will not exist, so will likely trigger a warning when checking for a value of true, so you should probably swap for the more explicit:

```
!isset($filesread[$withoutExt]) && ($filesread[$withoutExt] !== true)
```

Comment: your assumption about the if statement is correct! The directory has multiple same filenames with different extensions. Such as film.mp4 and film.jpg. One more question, I printed the `$filesread` and get this:  `Array([filmname1]>1,[filmname2]>1,[filmname3]>1)`; As you said,  `$filesread` is an array containing file names without an extension as keys, but how does `$filesread` get all the file names as its keys (what I know is $filesread is an empty array at the first time)? Which part of the code did this assignment? Also, why all the value in `$filesread`` is 1? Thanks!

Comment: `$filesread[$withoutExt] = true;` is where the assignment happens.  $withoutExt is the result of the preg_replace.

Comment: Do you mean `$filesread[$withoutExt] = true;` assign `$withoutExt` as the key to `$filesread` array? Also, can you please tell me why all the value in `$filesread` array is 1. Base on `$filesread[$withoutExt] = true;`, shouldn't the value be true?

Comment: Yes, assign `true` as the value for the key `$withoutExt` in `$filesread`.  You are likely seeing a value of 1 from a `print_r` on the array.  Try a `var_dump`, it's more revealing for types and values stored within.